# Использование вкладок в C#

Tags: c#, вкладки

Не отображаются гистограмма в модальном окне. Дабы не создавать по десять окон решил использовать вкладки в модальном окне, для гистограммы и таблицы, но ни гистограмма ни таблица не строятся. Подскажите, что нужно еще прописывать в коде при использовании вкладок, может пример? В текстбокс вводятся 24 числа столбиком, без запятых, после чего производятся расчеты, на основе которых как раз и строятся гистограмма и таблица. Без использования вкладок все исправно работает.

Comment: @Korol_tref, Вы бы, для начала, указали какой фреймворк используете и с помощью чего строите гистограммы

Comment: @Korol_tref, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Фреймворк 4.5. Гистограммы через Chart.

Comment: @Korol_tref: Тут интересен собственно _графический_ фреймворк: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Windows Forms